# setup azure machine with docker for play-framework application

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine, docker-machine

I am new to Azure and trying to setup my dockerized play-framework 2.5.x application there following this post:

[Azure Linux Docker Machine setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/docker-machine)

However, it always failed on the first command:

```
docker-machine create -d azure \
--azure-subscription-id $sub \
--azure-ssh-user azureuser \
--azure-open-port 80 \
myvm
```

error:

```
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err     : exit status 1
output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited 
with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
```

There are a lot of posts in Microsoft's website for azure setup, but everything is in pieces. I have followed through numerous of those and they just end up with new entries in my dashboard which just adds to my bill but I still can not have access to any of those to deploy my app. This is really frustating as I have spent days and almost runs out of my free $200 credits.

Any help, or any link to a WORKING setup is very highly appreciated

Comment: Please run this command to show the version of docker-machine `docker-machine version`. For now, the latest version is 0.12.1.

Comment: it is `docker-machine version 0.12.0, build 45c69ad`

Comment: Could you please update it to 0.12.1? By the way, does docker running on your computer, please run this command to check it `systemctl status docker.service`.  we can follow this link to install the latest version docker-machine   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/docker-machine

Comment: `systemctl: command not found` I am on mac, but I can verify that docker daemon is running, I can build and push docker images too from my local machine

Comment: the problem is the remote, I think those errors are thrown from the remote, but after that command, I can no longer access the remote. I have searched through each entries in `https://portal.azure.com` to no avail

Comment: access the remote? do you mean you can't remote the VM on Azure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150687/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-zennichimaro).

Comment: yes, I can't access the VM on azure,,, M$ $*ck, I am trying it out on aws now and can easily ssh into the box and do the docker command

Comment: yeah, seems like the ip is not reachable publicly. I remembered having to configure it to be in the public network but I can't remember the step and didn't do it at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, maybe we should **update the version of `docker-machine` to the latest version**.

> People cannot use the command to create a docker host. The issue has
>   been fixed in 0.12.1, and actually, the 0.12.2 has been released for a
>   while. However, the version of docker-machine inside Docker for Mac is
>   still 0.12.0.

`docker-machine` 0.12.0 has a serious issue, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1875).

Comment: no, it is working on aws, but I will give it a try once I go back to azure again

Comment: @Zennichimaro You can't login the Azure VM? wrong private key? or this VM was not running?

Comment: @Zennichimaro Does the VM running, or when we try to login it, error is "Permission denied (publickey)"?

Comment: wow, updating the `docker-machine` binary works! I will give azure another shot

Comment: @Zennichimaro Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved:)

Comment: Thanks a lot, while you're here do you know of any resources where I can get up to speed with configuring multiple instances and auto-scaling on azure with docker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150704/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-zennichimaro).

Comment: @Zennichimaro I guess your are looking for Azure container service, please refer to this article.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/